# What do you call a closet for school material?

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary, image-identification

What is the name of this "wardrobe" I use for putting the student's material and books?

Closet? Wardrobe? Cabinet?

[image: image of cupboard/bookcase/cabinet with doors]

Comment: In English, we ask *What do you call...?* not *How do you call...?*

Comment: @Clare -  Here closet closet closet....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The general word is [**cabinet**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/cabinet)

> A cupboard with drawers or shelves for storing or displaying articles

When used as you show, it's generally called a **supply cabinet** or a **storage cabinet**. Wikipedia has an article for [**stationery cabinet**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationery_cabinet) that describes the same thing, but I don't think I've ever heard that term (and the article is missing citations); it could be regional. I can't find much in the way of dictionary-style citations for my phrases, either, but googling them brings up lots of retail sites that sell products with these names.

If it's a small room, rather than a standalone device, it's then called a **supply closet**. Often a supply closet will contain several cabinets.

Comment: Also, students will often have individual storage locations.  These are called **lockers**, since each student has an individual locking device.  **Locker rooms** in athletic facilities are named after the same, individual, lockable cabinets.

Comment: @RichF And classrooms often have a rack of shelves where each student gets one little shelf, these are called **cubbyholes**.